# Angular.js authentication redirect not working with Yeoman Angular-Fullstack

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using the ngRouter and I am having in issue with the code below:

```
# Add Video
.when '/videos/:action',
  templateUrl: 'app/videos/videos-edit/videos-form.html'
  controller: 'VideosEditCtrl'
  authenticate: true

# Edit video
.when '/videos/:action/:year/:month/:slug',
  templateUrl: 'app/videos/videos-edit/videos-form.html'
  controller: 'VideosEditCtrl'
  authenticate: true
```

If I go to the edit video page above and I am not logged in, it redirects to the login page just like I want. However, if I do the same to the add video page, the url in the browser changes to the login page but it still shows the view for add video.

I can remove the authenticate:true from the add video controller and it seems to work by somehow still using the edit video authenticate but I am not sure why or how.

I want to use one controller for adding and editing a video since the code is so similar. Am I doing something wrong with my routing? Should I split the controller up?

Answer (score 0):

Add 'preventDefault()' in app.js.

i.e.

```
//before
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
// Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
    if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
});

//after
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, Auth) {
// Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
    if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
});
```